# Regex - Match line but with exception (! hyphen)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to filter the event log based on regex but I'm unable to figure it out yet.

Scenario 1): I want to match the full line starting with `Account Name` but I don't want to match the line if it has `- (hyphen)` only that. But it should match `-test-user`.

I tried `(Account Name:.*(!-).*)` but it isn't working.

Content:

```
Account Name:       -
Account Name:       testing
```

Scenario 2): I want to try matching the second `Account name` line with or without hyphen in the `Account For Which Logon Failed` section and not from `Subject` section.

I tried `(Account Name:.*){2}` but it isn't working.

Content:

```
Account Name:       -
Account Name:       testing
```

Scenario 3): Combine both Scenario, Match the second `Account name` line but only it has no `- (hyphen)`. If the second `Account name` has only hyphen then don't match anything but it should match `-test-user`.

I'm trying to learn here that's why I want to figure out all three scenario. Eventually I'll use only the last one.

Here is the full content:

```
Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       testing
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/w20LwU/1) what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this answers your question

```
/Account Name:\s*[^-][a-z]+$/gm
```

You can find the working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/okaVtk/1)

if you want to match all the special characters excluding `-` then you can use

```
/Account Name:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^&*()_+=[\]{}|\\,.?:<>'"\/;`%]+.*$/gm
```

You can include any special character in the list that you want inside `[]`

[updated example](https://regex101.com/r/batfbC/2)

Comment: it does match `testing` but what if the account name has special characters? Is it possible to match like wildcard `.*` at the end?

Comment: There is one small problem. If the username is `test-user` then it won't match anything. If I add the `- hyphen` then both lines gets matched. You think you can fix that too?

Comment: Hi @John if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: there is still a problem. If the username starts with `-test-user` then it won't work. Any solution for that? I've updated the question as well.